# XEN virtual machine with IPv6 but without IPv4

Tags: xen, ipv6

How should I create a new virtual machine using xen-create-image if I just got the IPv6 from my hoster?

When I tried

```
xen-create-image --hostname=s1.example.com --size=70Gb --swap=8Gb --memory=4096Mb
           --arch=amd64 --role-udev --ip=IPV6_ADDRESS --gateway=IPV6_ADDRESS
```

it is giving me that the IP and gateway should be in format of IPv4 and if I will remove those options, then it is giving me error that I need to specify the IP address.

Should I create then my local IPv4 network or how should this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code at https://github.com/xtaran/xen-tools/blob/master/bin/xen-create-image, the script doesn't appear to support IPv6.